# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST in

Tags: php, json, request

My code:

```
function jsonCall()
{

    global $_SESSION;
    global $smarty;

    $client_id = "XXXXXXXX";
    $next_max_tag_id = 1349756086082;

    if(isset($_POST['nextSubmit']))
        {
            $next_max_tag_id = $_POST['next_max_tag_id'];
        }


    $url ='https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' . $_SESSION['zoekterm'] . '/media/recent?access_token=145408254.f59def8.448ef83c8fa740aa9744a0c47766a857&max_tag_id=' . $next_max_tag_id;

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_output = json_decode($json,true);

    file_put_contents('json/instagram.json',$json);

    $imagesErbuiten = array();

            foreach($json_output['data'] as $data)
            {
                foreach($data['images'] as $images)
                {
                    array_push($imagesErbuiten, $images);
                }
            }


    $smarty->assign('arrData',$imagesErbuiten);
    $smarty->assign('next_max_tag_id',$json_output['pagination']['next_max_tag_id']);
}
```

I am working with the Instagram API and Flickr API. Both get same errors when there is a value they don't know in their searchfield.

As an example:

Instagram doesn't allow searches by tag like porn, tits, ... When this happens you get the 400 Bad request. When you search for QSDFQSDFQSDFQSDF (which doesn't exist ether) there is no error, just because the search is valid but the array is empty (which is good, so i can display "Nothing has been found").

It's not a empty space problem. I allready excluded all empty spaces and replaced them with a +.

My question:

Is it possible to just drop or fix this error? Everything works fine, except you get that ugly error at the top of my page.

Greetings,
W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative is to use cURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get more details about the request before the print:

Some like this maybe can help you:

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //get the code of request
    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpCode == 400) 
       return 'No donuts for you.';

    if($httpCode == 200) //is ok?
       return $output;


}
```

Comment: Helped out perfectly. The response they get now is:

"You bad boy! Don't search for porn here!
You'll see some popular instapics now." 

I also had a 403 BAD REQUEST, so i could fixed that one too. You just helped out 5 students (and a teacher) with the same problem. Thank you very much!