# Facebook Login Error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to follow the example to create a server side login to Facebook from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login), but with no luck. In step 7, when I try to exchange the code with a token and store it in a session for later use, I always get this error :

```
  file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

I know this already asked many times, but I still unable to solve this, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839065/failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1-1-400-bad-request-in), I tried using cURL, but it still does not work, it just returned false.

[Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141941/function-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed-http-1) told me to use the PHP SDK, but I don't know which method to use. So I'm completely lost in here.

---

Here's my code for calling the login form :

```
<a href="<?php echo LOGIN_URL; ?> ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>
```

where LOGIN_URL is defined as :

```
define("LOGIN_URL", $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("redirect_uri" => APP_URL . "fb_login")));
```

in fb_login, I have this code :

```
$app->get("/fb_login", function() use($app, $facebook)
{
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . APP_URL . $_SESSION["request_uri"] // Previous URL
       . "&client_secret=" . APP_SECRET . "&code=" . $code;

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url); // Doesn't work
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $_SESSION["access_token"] = $params["access_token"];

    // Let's try with cURL...
    // $ch = curl_init();
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // $output = curl_exec($ch); // Returns false
    // curl_close($ch);

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
      . $params["access_token"];

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    echo("Hello " . $user->name);

    var_dump($code); die();
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks before.

Comment: Can you paste the full value of `$token_url` so we can see the final value of the variable after appending all the different variables?

Comment: _Any_ debugging efforts of your own …?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly answer the question, the problem is most likely that you do not `urlencode` (make safe for URL transport) the redirect URL. The fastest fix will be:

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(APP_URL . $_SESSION["request_uri"])
   . "&client_secret=" . APP_SECRET . "&code=" . $code;
```

However, I would also suggest that you look at the Facebook SDK as this does this all for you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the documentation on the PHP SDK... Its quite extensive and nice.. You just need to setup your Facebook SDK as following

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'your app id',
                'secret'=> 'your app secret'));
```

Then you can retrieve login URL as

```
$loginURL = $facebook->loginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'read_stream',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://yourdomain/path/to/page'));
```

And moreover it, SDK might give you better description about your error which is handled by it which can be due to mismatch in redirect URI with app's configurations or error in app ID or secret or entirely different thing. Download SDK from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)